# react-floater issue, Bo is not a function when i am using this and import it into my library storybook

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, material-ui, storybook, storybook-addon

react-floater issue, Bo is not a function

i have created tooltip using react-floater and its working fine in my storybook library and when i am using it with my new react-app and import my library then its showing below error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

it's showing error in console

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, errors or other text. Copy the original text to your question and format it using the code format tool.